Failed to resolve: com.halfhp.fig:figlib:1.0.7 (mavenCentral/jcenter?)
I'm building an Android app in Kotlin. I want it to have graphs and I'm using
implementation(libs.androidplot.core)

in my build.gradle file. But I get the following error when reloading the Gradle project:
Failed to resolve: com.halfhp.fig:figlib:1.0.7
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

The advice on the internet is roughly this:
What is the correct way of changing jcenter to mavenCentral?
To change jcenter() to mavenCentral(). However, my build.gradle looks the following and I don't know how to change to source of dependencies correctly - there is no "buildscripts" section:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapp"
        minSdk = 32
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.ui.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.legacy.support.v4)
    implementation(libs.androidx.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidplot.core)
    implementation ("com.halfhp.fig:figlib:1.0.7")
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}



However, my build.gradle looks the following and I don't know how to change to source of dependencies correctly - there is no "buildscripts" section:

You probably already have mavenCentral() configured. On newer projects, the default is to configure this in settings.gradle or settings.gradle.kts in a dependencyResolutionManagement() lambda:
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

Your problem is your version. Replace:
    implementation ("com.halfhp.fig:figlib:1.0.7")

with:
    implementation ("com.halfhp.fig:figlib:1.0.11")

1.0.11 is the only version reported to be in Maven Central.
Also, please note that this project has not been updated in 3 years.

Thank you! It fixed the problem. Good to know where to check the dependencies (Maven Central link). The reference to maven central is in fact in settings.gradle.kts.

Do you have any newer recommendations of plotting libraries?

@ElisHazelton: No, sorry!
